# pytorch move model to gpu causes runtime error ('self' as cpu device type)

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytorch, gpu

**Solved** by adding `.to(device)` for each weights and bias like `t.Tensor(w_txt[0]).to(device))` and it works perfectly on gpu!

---

My network works well on cpu, and I try to move my network to gpu by adding some commented lines as follows.

```py
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F

device = t.device("cuda:0" if t.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

def mapminmax(data,dim):
    min = np.min(data,axis=dim)
    max = np.max(data,axis=dim)
    return (data-min)/(max-min)

w_h1 = np.loadtxt('hidden1weight.txt')
w_h2 = np.loadtxt('hidden2weight.txt')
w_h3 = np.loadtxt('hidden3weight.txt')
w_h4 = np.loadtxt('predictweight.txt')
w_txt = np.array([w_h1,w_h2,w_h3,w_h4])
b_h1 = np.loadtxt('hidden1bias.txt')
b_h2 = np.loadtxt('hidden2bias.txt')
b_h3 = np.loadtxt('hidden3bias.txt')
b_h4 = np.loadtxt('predictbias.txt')
b_txt = np.array([b_h1,b_h2,b_h3,b_h4])

def parameter_init_self():
    model.hidden1.weight = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(w_txt[0]))
    model.hidden2.weight = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(w_txt[1]))
    model.hidden3.weight = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(w_txt[2]))
    model.predict.weight = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(w_txt[3]))
    model.hidden1.bias = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(b_txt[0]))
    model.hidden2.bias = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(b_txt[1]))
    model.hidden3.bias = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(b_txt[2]))
    model.predict.bias = t.nn.Parameter(t.Tensor(b_txt[3]))

class DNNF(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size1, hidden_size2, hidden_size3, output_size):
        super(DNNF, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = t.nn.Linear(input_size, hidden1_size)
        self.hidden2 = t.nn.Linear(hidden1_size, hidden2_size)
        self.hidden3 = t.nn.Linear(hidden2_size, hidden3_size)
        self.predict = t.nn.Linear(hidden3_size, output_size)
        # self = self.cuda()
    def forward(self, x):
        x = t.tanh(self.hidden1(x)) # line 88
        x = t.tanh(self.hidden2(x))
        x = t.tanh(self.hidden3(x))
        y_pred = self.predict(x)
        return y_pred


x_df = pd.read_csv('InputData_Train.csv', header=None)
y_df = pd.read_csv('OutputData_Train.csv', header=None)
x = t.tensor(x_df.values).float()
y = t.tensor(y_df.values).float()
M = x.size()[0]
input_size = x.size()[1]
output_size = y.size()[1]
hidden1_size, hidden2_size, hidden3_size = 50, 50, 50
x_np = x.numpy()
y_np = y.numpy()
x_norm_np = mapminmax(x_np,0)
y_norm_np = mapminmax(y_np,0)
x = t.from_numpy(x_norm_np)
y = t.from_numpy(y_norm_np)
x = Variable(x, requires_grad=False)
y = Variable(y, requires_grad=False)

# x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)  # move to gpu

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

lr = 1e-2
mm = 0.9
EPOCH = 300

model = DNNF(input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, hidden3_size, output_size)
# model = model.to(device)  # move to gpu

parameter_init_self()

param = {}
for name, para in model.named_parameters():
    param[name] = para.detach().numpy()

optimizer = t.optim.Rprop(model.parameters(), lr=lr)  # lr=1e-2

DISPINTERVAL = 10

for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    y_pred = model(x) # line 172
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    if (epoch + 1) % DISPINTERVAL == 0:
        print('Epoch[{}/{}], loss:{:.10f}'.format(epoch+1, EPOCH, loss.item()))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

y_pred = model(x)
E = y - y_pred
SE = E*E
MSE = t.mean(SE)
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)

print('MSE: ', MSE.item())
print('loss: ', loss.item())
```

However I got this error

```
Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_addmm
  File "E:\MachineLearning\PyTorch\a2MLP_V6_GPU.py", line 88, in forward
    x = t.tanh(self.hidden1(x))
  File "E:\MachineLearning\PyTorch\a2MLP_V6_GPU.py", line 172, in <module>
    y_pred = model(x)
```

I tried to search on google but got no answer, the most mentioned thing is that there may be parameters defined within the model that are not moved to gpu. But as far as I can see, there is no such parameter in my model.

The error indicates that the problem is around `self` parameter and I don't know about it since it is not a parameter defined by me. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: did you try `model(x).cuda()` ? Try this and tell.

Comment: @Pygirl Tried and failed. The error still exists.

Comment: It could be due to the loading of weights and bias.

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks a lot! I added `.to(device)` for each weights and bias like  `t.Tensor(w_txt[0]).to(device))` and it works perfectly on gpu! :-)